# Anular Control+V (Pegar) en JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Tengo un fichero `.fxml` donde he definido un control `PasswordField` y un evento `KeyPressed`:

```
<PasswordField fx:id="clave" onKeyPressed="#teclaPulsada" prefWidth="170.0" />
```

Quiero evitar que alguien pegue una clave copiada y así forzar que se teclee. Estoy probando con el siguiente código para detectar la tecla *control* o *comando* (según sea win o mac) pero no sé como detectar al mismo tiempo la tecla v (control/comando + v)

```
@FXML
    void teclaPulsada(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
       if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.COMMAND) {
          System.out.println("pulsado command");
          keyEvent.consume();

          if (keyEvent.getText() == "v") {
             System.out.println("pulsada la v");
             keyEvent.consume();
          }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes utilizar un listener para una instancia de la clase [`KeyCodeCombination`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCodeCombination.html):

```
final KeyCodeCombination keyComb = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.V, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
miPasswordField.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, event -> {
    if (keyComb.match(event)) {
        System.out.println("Se ha presionado Ctrl+V.");          
    }
});
```